# posting a swf in facebook feed through facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, feed

I am using the below array and

```
$feeddata = array(
                    'type'=>'flash',
                    'method'=>'stream.publish',
                    'display'=>'iframe',
          'link'=> 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          'source'=>'http://www.hackerdude.com/channels-test/swfscout_VideoSample.swf',
         'picture'=> 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          'name'=> 'Facebook Dialogs',
          'caption'=> 'Reference Documentation',
          'description'=> 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.');
```

and passing it to facebook->api($userid.'/feed', 'POST', $feeddata );
But in the feed i can see only the image and when i click in the image it takes me to the link, how can i see swf in the feed (ideally on clicking on the picture it should toggle to swf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `type` should be "video" instead of "flash". Here's a parameter array that produced a playable video in my tests:

```
array(
    'type'=>'video',
    'source'=>'http://www.hackerdude.com/channels-test/swfscout_VideoSample.swf',
    'picture'=> 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    'name'=> 'Facebook Dialogs',
    'caption'=> 'Reference Documentation',
    'description'=> 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',
);
```

**Note** that there's no `link` attribute, that's because as it seems to me, the facebook API has a bug at this moment where if you provide a link then it won't embed your video.

The bug theory reinforced by that the JS SDK does indeed accept a link and produce a playable video, you could migrate to this method for publishing if its feasable, with parameters like this:

```
FB.ui({
     method:'feed',
     type: 'video',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     source: 'http://www.hackerdude.com/channels-test/swfscout_VideoSample.swf',
     description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
});
```

### Workaround

The embedding seem to be working fine if you post a link that has the proper opengraph meta tags for video embedding, here's an example:

**the link to be shared** (video brought to you by youtube)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fly, you fools!</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Fly, you fools!" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Content for Description" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/meOCdyS7ORE/mqdefault.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Content for caption"/>
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/meOCdyS7ORE?version=3&autohide=1">
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="640">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="360">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.location = 'http://disney.com'; // redirecting users who's clicking on the link, wont affect crawlers since its in js.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**php sdk call to share it**

```
$this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    'type' => 'link',
    'link' => 'http://.../', // put the html file's location here
));
```

Comment: doing the same thing now, but clicking on the image is taking me to a new tab with the swf open in it , it is not toggling image to swf itself over there.

Comment: Yes, this is what happens with me too, when posting trough the Graph API, (the name linked to the swf file too) as i wrote. I think its a bug, created a [bugreport](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/502967809730190).

Comment: i posted it , underscore had the problem , a bug from fb side only

Comment: Me too facing same issue when I post to facebook the first thumb will load with flash play button but when I saw it on timeline only link is showing, its not showing any images and flash player

Answer (score 1):

write one more met tag : 
`<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://...game url.">`
"

try to put "https:// " game url ,i.e game swf url with ssl, because fb takes only ssl url to play videos or swf file for game.

Hope this will be useful.