# Graph API post of video is not playable

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video

I have an application that posts music videos from YouTube to a Facebook user's wall. The post on Facebook would have this embed video be playable from Facebook. Recently it stopped happening.

After some testing, it seems that when one makes the graph API post with the source being a YouTube video, then the link also needs `youtube.com` in the domain for it to be playable within a Facebook context.

To repeat:

You can take a look for yourself by logging into Facebook and going here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Then get an access token with `read_stream` and `publish_stream` permissions (extended permissions tab).

Switch from `GET` to `POST` and set the endpoint to /me/feed with the following fields:

```
message = message
description = description
name = name
caption = caption
link = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1dfEf1qOt4
source = http://www.youtube.com/e/r1dfEf1qOt4
picture = http://img.youtube.com/vi/r1dfEf1qOt4/0.jpg
```

It should show up on your Facebook wall and be playable.

Now do it again, but change the link to http://www.google.com.
It is no longer playable.

Can anyone confirm if this is expected behavior? I can't find anything in the Facebook docs. Perhaps I am just missing something?

Comment: Why should the link to google.com be playable?, there is no videos in google.com . Maybe i am not understanding your question.

Comment: It is not the 'link' that is playable, it is the video source that I embedded. If I post a youtube video to facebook, why would it not be playable within facebook, simply because the link doesn't take you to the origin domain of the video? That is what the case seems to be. I am looking for confirmation that this is indeed the case and documented somewhere or seeking out a possible remedy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Generalized Workaround

[I generalized the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11651634/1085891) to this similar question: [posting a swf in facebook feed through facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649932/posting-a-swf-in-facebook-feed-through-facebook-api). I created a page that takes two parameters and generates the necessary `meta` tags. Facebook accepts the link, the user is correctly redirected, and you don't need a separate page for each posted video.

1. `url` - the final URL
2. `id` - the id of the youtube or embedded video

I successfully made numerous embedded posts in which the link was not associated with the video.

#### Example Post

```
message = Post message
description = Post description if needed.
name = Post name
caption = Post caption
link = http://vbcopper.com/jsuar/so/fbembedvideo.php?url=stackoverflow.com&id=QGAJokcwBXI
source = http://www.youtube.com/e/QGAJokcwBXI
picture = http://img.youtube.com/vi/QGAJokcwBXI/0.jpg
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
 $id =  $_GET["id"];
 $url =  $_GET["url"];

 if ( isset($url) ) {
echo <<< EOT
<html>
<head>
    <title>$url</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Page Title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Content for Description" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/$id/mqdefault.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Content for caption"/>
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/$id?version=3&autohide=1">
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="640">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="360">
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=http://$url">

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
EOT;
} else {
    echo "Nothing here...";
}
?>
```

### Findings

I was able to successfully replicate your issue. <strike>I could find no work around.</strike>

This has been submitted as a bug to Facebook but deemed low priority.

> Bugs: Posting video to feed with link attribute doesn't embed the source
>   https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/502967809730190?browse=search_5074a2e48fd360934230075

Comment: A javascript workaround is not what I am looking for, especially since you are suggesting that I need to make pages like the following for the content that users share and link to that, which seems just too hacky for my liking. Just to clarify, just if it was unclear, I am talking about facebook context, in which I have no control over their javascript. I am posting through PHP Graph API and am not looking for a workaround like this. However, I do appreciate the time spent.

Comment: Understood. Based on my findings it looks like what you're after isn't available. Either because facebook no longer allows it or due to a bug.

Comment: @agentile, I recommend checking out my generalized solution above. It works well based on my tests. You only need to create one page which works as a central redirect page based on some `GET` parameters. Looks like a decent workaround.

Comment: @agentile Did my generalized solution help?

Answer (score 0):

Normally to share YouTube videos to Facebook pages you only need message, link, source, 
picture parameters. Even you can also skip the source, picture parameters if you wish to. Thats is if you are using FacebookC#SDK to share video to Facebook all you need is following code

```
 var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(yourPageAccessToken); 
 argList["message"] = message;
 argList["link"] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + specialOffer.YoutubeId;
 argList["source"] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + specialOffer.YoutubeId;
 argList["picture"] = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + specialOffer.YoutubeId + "/0.jpg";
 fb.Post("feed", argList);
```

or

```
 var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(yourPageAccessToken); 
 argList["message"] = message;
 argList["link"] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + specialOffer.YoutubeId;
 fb.Post("feed", argList);
```