# Sharing video on Facebook like Youtube

Tags: facebook, video

I am developing a video sharing button for our streaming platform.
But I find it difficult to have Facebook implement the video as a "video"

Can anyone see whats missing in order for Facebook to interpret this page as a video and make it playable inline on facebook?

http://cdn.simplestreamtech.com/share/7ig8TbtC

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the OpenGraph `video.other` object to publish this to Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/video.other/

Also, have a look an the answer here: [Graph API post of video is not playable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613008/graph-api-post-of-video-is-not-playable)

Comment: Yes I am already posting as video.other and included all mandatory meta tagging. However Facebook does not make it playable. Thats the problem!